# Automapper only creates new object without map

Tags: c#, automapper, automapper-11

I have two objects which I can't map.

[image]

Here are my objects definitions:

```cs
public class DcMarkupValue
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; }
    public decimal MarkupPrice { get; }
    public decimal MarkupChange { get; }
}

public class MarkupByUOMandCategoryIdEntity
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public decimal MarkupPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal MarkupChange { get; set; }
    public decimal MarkupPercentChange { get; set; }
    public string UomCode { get; set; }
}
```

In this example, you can see that Automapper does not perform the mapping. `StartDate` field not mapped. What have I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `setter` to each property in `DcMarkupValue`.

```cs
public class DcMarkupValue
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public decimal MarkupPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal MarkupChange { get; set; }
}
```